# Logging Cell in CollectionView

Tags: iphone, uitableview, nsarray, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I have a view with a full screen collectionView who's cells are also full screen; one cell is viewable at a time (let's assume it's iPhone 5 only to make it simple). In the code below I'm logging which cell is loaded:

```
- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
    {
        CollectionViewCell *cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"CollectionCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];
        NSObject *someObject = [someArray  objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        cell.someLabel.text = [someObject valueForKey:@"label"];

        NSLog(@"index:%d",[someArray indexOfObject:someObject]);
    }
```

When I scroll even one pixel down (the collectionView scrolls vertically), the `index:` moves from `0` to `1`. When I scroll back up that same pixel, it still reads `1`. Obviously, scrolling down that one pixel only shows one pixel of the second cell, which is logged. Scrolling back up shows the entire 1st cell but doesn't log `0`.

How do I log which cell is currently entirely in the view?

Answer (score 0):

Try this. It may help you.

```
NSArray *arr = [collectionView indexPathsForVisibleItems];
if ([arr count]!=0) {
   NSLog(@"%@",[arr objectAtIndex:0]);
}
```